# File system atomic access with NodeJS/SailsJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, sails.js, atomic

I currently have an application in NodeJS (using the sails.js framework) that runs with more than 1 instance (using PM2). On app sart I want to access a folder and read the contents of the files inside that folder. But only one process must do that. I'm trying to achieve something like *directory locking*, but I know there's some problems with this operation being atomic. 
I want some thoughts on this. How can I achieve a rock-solid solution that helps me implement this?

Comment: There is [fs-ext](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-ext), allowing you to lock files. You could traverse a directory and lock all files.

Comment: @ShanShan fs-ext will provide atomic read-write operations on different workers?

Comment: I had a quick look at the code source and there is some [C code](https://github.com/baudehlo/node-fs-ext/blob/master/fs-ext.cc). The lock happens at OS/filesystem level so no other process (nodejs or not) won't be able to access the locked file. If the only processes manipulating the files are yours, there is much easier way, use a `.lock` file and have your processes manage it (check if it exists in the current directory, create it to lock, delete when job is done...).